# if no child categories then return categories of same level

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, category, filter

In magento CE 1.7.0.2 `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View` function `_getCategoryFilter()` `$this->getChild('category_filter')` returns list of child category.

```
protected function _getCategoryFilter()
{
    return $this->getChild('category_filter');
}
```

What I want is, if '$this->getChild('category_filter')->getItemsCount()` returns zero then I want list of categories of same level.

Say following is category structure:

```
1.root
|-- 2. cat1 
    |--2a. subcat1
    |--2b. subcat2
```

How I can modify `_getCategoryFilter()` as `2a` has not child category ( '$this->getChild('category_filter')` will return zero) then it will return what its parent had return ie '2a, 2b'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get Sibling Categories:

Inside your if condition

```
$parentId=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id)->getParentId();
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId)->getChildrenCategories();
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
  // first, skip current category.
  if ($cat->getId() == Mage::registry('current_category')->getId()) continue;
  // then do something with $cat
  echo $cat->getName().", ";
}
```

This [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795810/magento-showing-sibling-categories-in-layered-navigation) may help you more.

Comment: I have updated question. Please take a look.

Comment: I have added a link, i guess Rehan's answer can be your key

Comment: I tried your solution but In filter all other subcategories except selected one having getProductCount() zero. How I can get exactly same category filter block as parent category is active? Say If Animal category is selected then categories as cats (3), Dogs(5), Lions(4) then if Dogs is selected then cats and lions show active links with positive product count.

Comment: You will need to get the parent id of current category, and then get the child of that parent category, thats what my code, and the link i shared did